# Generic Textchange Event

Tags: jquery, validation, dynamic, numbers

I am creating a android phonegap app, I want to create a generic textbox number validation for entering only numbers (0-9). No decimals(.). I can easily do it by passing different 10 different id to 10 different jquery function. but i want it to be generic without me passing 10 different ids.

I was successfully able to do it. http://jsfiddle.net/JG99G/30/ but somewhere I coudnt find it robust and was looking forward to something like

```
$('input[type="textarea"]').on('keydown',function (e) {
  //Code
});
```

I have not put the number validation code inside.

Comment: Can't you just give the elements a common class, such as `digitsonly` or something, and then just bind an event handler to that class?

Comment: Thanks, That helped http://jsfiddle.net/JG99G/33/ but my concern is that wont it affect the class that JQM will set dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're applying the class dynamically, you'll need to use `.on()` and *delegate* the event to `.digitsonly`, like so:-

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.digitsonly', function(e) {
  // your code
});
```

#### [Here's a simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JG99G/34/)